# What is the meaning of 提出図書?

Tags: translation, words, lexicalization

This is the title of a technical document:

> 性能評価用提出図書（別添）作成要領

What is the meaning of 提出図書? Is it "document to submit"? On dictionaries, 図書 is translated as book, but in this case I think it is simply a document (later on it is stated 図書サイズは、特に指定されたもの以外はＡ４判としてください). Here is my translation attempt:

> Guidelines for the preparation of a 'Document (attachment) to submit for quality evaluation'

Also, could you please confirm that 別添 means attachment? In the first paragraph of the document it is repeated (本書類は、性能評価用提出図書 (別添)です), so even though it is between parenthesis it seems an important detail.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are totally correct.

At first I thought 図書 means a book, but it is definitely a document if it is written in another document that "本書類は、性能評価用提出図書 (別添)です".

This usage of 図書 is not common and only seen in documents for governmental procedures.

And yes, 別添 means attachment. To break it down, it can read as 別に添える, "attach separately." So it indicates that "性能評価用提出図書 (別添)" is a separate document that should be attached to a main document when submitted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you provide some info on 提出 too? Does the whole expression 提出図書 have a particular meaning?

Comment: @Marco 提出 can be looked at as a verb 提出する (to submit). So 提出図書 can be interpreted as "提出**する**図書" (a document to submit) or "提出**すべき**図書" (a document that should be submitted). 　 This (suru-verb) + (noun) construction is a common way to create a compound noun, especially for 漢語. So 提出図書 has no more special meaning than 提出 + 図書.